# Wordpress: Access URL for post which was just created

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create a website which allows users to upload files of hiking paths (gpx (xml) files).

To do this the user access a page called "Create new track" (this is a WordPress page with a specific template). Via a php created form, the user enters the name of the hike, a short description and chooses the file to upload. My code then makes the usual checks on the entered data and chosen file. If all checks are passed, the file is uploaded to the server and a new post is created (adding the entered title and description and file attached to the post).

I want that once the file has been uploaded and the new post has been created then the user accesses a webpage where he can view the newly created hike. I would like this page to be a second WordPress page called "Edit track" which uses a second specific template.

My current plan is that would use $track_ID (see code - this is the ID of the newly created post) and add this to the url of the "Edit track" url in the form of a url parameter. When the "Edit track page is automatically opened after successful creation of the track then the url param is read and the appropriate track can be edited.

My problem is, what code do I need to write such that once the new post is successfully created the "Edit track" page is accessed??

I am completely stumped! I have tried using php and Javascript, but cannot workout how to do this. All ideas welcome!

The frame of my code is attached.

```
add_shortcode('sut_form', 'sut_form_shortcode');

function sut_form_shortcode() {

    if (isset( $_POST['sut_form_create_track_submitted'] ) &&
        wp_verify_nonce($_POST['sut_form_create_track_submitted'], 'sut_form_create_track') ) { 

        // LOTS OF CHECKS ON WHAT HAS BEEN ENTERED
    }
    else // ALL CHECKS PASSED, SO WE CAN CREATE THE POST
    {
        $track_data = array(
            'post_title' => $sut_track_name,
            'post_content' => $sut_track_text,
            'post_status' => 'pending',
            'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
            'post_type' => 'tracks'     
        );

        // Create track post and attach image
        if ($track_id = wp_insert_post($track_data)) {  // POST CREATED

            wp_set_object_terms( $track_id, (int)$_POST['sut_track_category'], 'track_category'); // CATEGORY ASSIGNED TO POST
            update_field('field_5bf39d97d1e8d', $movefile['url'], $track_id); // UPLOADED FILE ATTACHED TO POST

            // PROBLEM!!! HOW  DO I KNOW ACCESS THE URL FOR POST WHICH HAS JUST BEEN CREATED? 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `get_permalink( $track_id );`

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I can either use a little javascript once the post was created - but then, how do I pass $track_ID to the Javascript? Or I could use php code, but then, what php code can open a new url?

Comment: use `header("Location: URL"):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is registered with add_shortcode, so it is executed during page content rendering, it is too late to use header("location... since headers could be already sent to client.

The only solution I can think of, without changing your code and without knowing your entire project is to print a JavaScript snippet, something like this:

```
$permalink = get_permalink($track_id);
echo("<script>window.location.replace('$permalink');</script>");
```

It is not too neat but should work.

Comment: SUCCESS! Thanks for this and thanks for explaining about how/when functions are registered with shortcodes. Did not know this. Thank you.